# External file changes sync may be slow

Tags: android-studio

I'm an ubuntu 13.10 user and installed android-studio-bundle-135.1245622-linux.tgz
but when run it using terminal command :
`./studio.sh`, it opens but below error appears:

```
External file changes sync may be slow
Native file watcher is not executable: /home/tahtawy/Desktop/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier64
```

and I can't open it throw lancher
so, How can I solve this problem.

Comment: The file needs to be made executable, see this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/601558/250674