# Android studio launch

Tags: android-studio

I'm an Ubuntu 14.04.1 user and installed `android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip`,
but when I run it using terminal command `./studio.sh`, it opens but an alert appears:

> External file changes sync may be slow
>
> Native file watcher is not executable: `/home/ron/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier`

and I can’t open it through launcher. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Try the following...

```
chmod +x /home/ron/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. No change.